# Python, удаление элемента из массива

Tags: python

```
i=0
lst=d
for i in range(dl):
    f=d[i]
    print f
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(f,mask):
        print "ff"
    else:
        print "file is not be reader"
        del lst[1]

    i=i+1
```

Массив lst дублирует массив d, после несоответствующие маске элементы массива должны быть удалены, но вместо этого питон ругается 
IndexError: list index out of range

причем вот в этом месте

```
f=d[i]
```

Хотя при удалении этой строки все работает

```
del lst[1]
```

Но мне нужно удалить несоответствующие маске элементы, кто знает в чем проблема?

Comment: dl опередлён?

Comment: Да, dl=len(d)

Answer (score 4):

Чему равен ваш "dl"? Если он больше чем размерность d - то в чем тогда вопрос? операцией:

```
del lst[1]
```

вы удаляете элемент не только из lst, но и из d. Что бы сделать копию d в lst - воспользуйтесь slice'ом:

```
lst = d[:]
```

ну это уже зависит от логики вашего скрипта в целом.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.

Comment: @Hdd, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 3):

в Python есть прекрасная функция "filter", возвращает список объектов, прошедших фильтрацию.

В Вашем случае можно написать что-то вроде такого:

```
import functools
filter_func = functools.partial(fnmatch.fnmatch, mask)
filter(filter_func, lst)
```

filter(filter_func, lst) вернет итератор по всем элементам списка lst, которые удовлетворяют маске.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала

```
from copy import deepcopy
lst = deepcopy(d) # вместо lst = d
```

Без этого lst и d будут ссылаться на один объект

Comment: Спасибо, помогло